# Pointers and .txt files

Tags: c, file, pointers

I have a minor question. 
This is for a programming assignment.
Open a file then using fgets() copy the contents of the file and then using fputs() paste the contents into a new file.

The below code only pastes a letter over and over again - this changes every time I have run it.

```
char buffer[41];
 FILE *fp_in;
 FILE *fp_out;
 fp_in =fopen(INPUTFILE, "rb");
    if (fp_in==NULL)
    {
        printf("File %s cannot be opened!\n", INPUTFILE);
        return;
    }
fp_out =fopen(OUTPUTFILE1, "wb");
if (fp_out==NULL)
    {
        printf("File %s cannot be opened!\n", OUTPUTFILE1);
        return;
     }
 printf("Reading from file using fgets()\n", INPUTFILE);
 printf("writing to file using fputs() \n", OUTPUTFILE1);
    fgets(buffer,41,fp_in);
    fputs(buffer,fp_out);
fclose(fp_in);
fclose(fp_out);
```

The adjustment below, using the actually file name to access the file instead of a pointer, does work and pastes the contents of the first file.

```
char buffer[41];
FILE *fp_in;
FILE *fp_out;
fp_in =fopen(INPUTFILE, "rb");
    if (fp_in==NULL)
    {
        printf("File %s cannot be opened!\n", INPUTFILE);
        return;
    }
fp_out =fopen("hurricane_out1.txt", "wb");
if (fp_out==NULL)
    {
        printf("File %s cannot be opened!\n", OUTPUTFILE1);
        return;
    }
printf("Reading from file using fgets()\n", INPUTFILE);
printf("writing to file using fputs() \n", OUTPUTFILE1);
    fgets(buffer,41,fp_in);
    fputs(buffer,fp_out);
fclose(fp_in);
fclose(fp_out);
```

My question is why does the above code work, when the first does not?

Comment: (Please clean up your post.) What are INPUTFILE and OUTPUTFILE1? (Unrelated: Why are you using `rb` and `wb` for what apparently are text files? Why are you trying to print the names of the files where the `printf` format string does not contain any `%s`?)

Comment: INPUTFILE is the file that I am copying text from, OUTPUTFILE1 is where I'm trying to paste the copied text, as for rb and wb is there another way to do it?

The printf statements were given as part of a template by our instructor.

Comment: You have a template that is using `printf` to write error messages?!  Ignore that template.